# Media query works on wrong screen size

Tags: css, media-queries, responsive

I'm trying to make my design responsive using CSS media query the problem is i need to have container specific width when the screen size between 992px and 1199px but the problem is that when the screen reach size 1080 it automatically apply another values from larger screen

Here's the screenshots showing the actual size of the screen and the applied media query

before reaching 1080px : http://prntscr.com/on8r04

after reaching 1080px: http://prntscr.com/on8rd4

this is the bootstrap screen sizes i'm using https://pastebin.com/YkH6LcUf

```css
@media (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px) { /*   medium devices */

    .container {
        width:800px !important;
    }
    .case-study .left-div {
        width:60%;
        left:0;
    }
    .case-study .right-img {
        width:500px;
        right:0;
    }

}
```

the container width should be 800px on screen sizes between 992px and 1199px but it doesn't

Answer (score 3):

Judging by the ratio `1080/1200 = 0.9`, I'm making a guess that your browser is in a wrong scale mode(which is 90%).

If that's the case, try to reset the zoom for your browser.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a general problem with your code, but there might be with the order you include the CSS or as @Hao Wu wrote, you might have unintentionally set your browser zoom, try to reset it by pressing `Ctrl/Cmd + 0`

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

window.addEventListener('resize', (e) => {
   container.dataset.width = container.getBoundingClientRect().width + 'px';
});

window.addEventListener('load', (e) => {
   container.dataset.width = container.getBoundingClientRect().width  + 'px';
});
```

```css
.container {
    background: lightcoral;
    height: 300px;
}
.container:before {
    content: attr(data-width);
}

@media (max-width:768px) { /*   mobiles */
 
    .container {
        width:750px;
    }
}
 
@media (min-width:768px) and (max-width:991px) { /*   small devices */
    .container {
        width:750px;
    }
}
 
@media (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px) { /*   medium devices */
    .container {
        width:970px;
    }
}
 
@media (min-width:1200px) { /*   large devices */
    .container {
        width:1270px;
    }
}


@media (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px) { /*   medium devices */

    .container {
        width:800px;
    }
}
```

```html
<section class="case-study">
  <div class="container">
  
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: It's probably not because of the order since `!important` is taken place. By the screenshot, when screen width reaches 1080px, the corresponding rules are disappeared, not just been overwritten.